# How to display one xml file in another. Reference of XML in another XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, cross-reference

I have an XML file called person.xml

I would like to display the contents of person.xml in display.xml

So if in future, if I edit the content of person.xml then it will get reflected on display.xml also.

I want kind of referencing for xml's.

For example person.xml consists of

person.xml :

```
<person>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>18</age>
    <hair>Brown</hair>
    <eyes>Blue</eyes>
</person>
```

So what should be the code of display.xml

I have currently display.xml as

```
<group>
  <personlink xlink:href="person.xml" xlink:show="embed" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
</group>
```

Comment: Neither XLink nor XInclude are supported by Microsoft's XML parsers respectively tools. DTD based references are supported, they have however poor support in other areas like browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external entity declared in a DTD as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE group [
  <!ENTITY person SYSTEM "person.xml">
]>
<group>
  &person;
</group>
```

Then in your .NET code you need to set up an XmlReader with XmlReaderSettings to allow DTDs and resolve URIs:

```
        XDocument doc;
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("../../display.xml", new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse, XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver() }))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(xr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

The result is then

```
<!DOCTYPE group [
  <!ENTITY person SYSTEM "person.xml">
]>
<group>

<person>
  <name>John</name>
  <age>18</age>
  <hair>Brown</hair>
  <eyes>Blue</eyes>
</person>

</group>
```